# Setting DISPLAY=:0 and XAUTHORITY=/home/pi/.Xauthority causes FFmpeg to run poorly

Tags: bash, debian, raspbian, ffmpeg, xdg

I've setup a webcam viewer that detects when a USB webcam is plugged in with a `udev` rule, then starts a `systemd` service that executes a script that starts an FFmpeg/FFplay webcam stream. I noticed when setting `DISPLAY=:0` and `XAUTHORITY=/home/pi/.Xauthority` in the script before FFmpeg is started FFmpeg will run the stream very poorly (Pi Zero W < 1fps).

On the Pi Zero W I left this bit out and it runs great when a webcam is plugged in but on a Pi 4 4GB the webcam viewer never comes up unless these environment variables are set. The logs say `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment`. Why would the stream work fine on the Zero W without these variables and not work at all on the Pi 4? Better yet, why does FFmpeg run terribly when these variables are set?

On the Pi 4 setting these variables does not seem to affect FPS.

Comment: Are you accessing this locally (x11 server on Pi) or remotely (X11 Forwarding -> client)? It sounds like maybe ffmpeg is trying to detect the hardware decoder or something. Can you try and check if `DISPLAY`, and `ffmpeg` run outside the script interactively gives any clue? Maybe also check out this https://www.reddit.com/r/raspberry_pi/comments/5677qw/hardware_accelerated_x264_encoding_with_ffmpeg/

Comment: This is when attempting locally. My setup is very similar to that link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating to Raspberry Pi OS Bullseye this issue appears to be fixed most likely due to them consolidating the video driver across all hardware. Unfortunately performance on Pi Zero W is worse on Bullseye. Oh well.